# Could not login to docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run my node.js app and mongodb using docker compose. I could setup the containers successfully as follows. The site is also working. But I could not ssh into the containers.

`docker ps -a`

**Output**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                            NAMES
68582ac4aa9a        projet/nodeserver      "/bin/bash -c 'sourc…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                                           apiserver
81b6c0c65e43        mongo                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                                         mongodb
```

Also I am able to connect with mongodb server using mongodb client from the host machine(Mac). But when I tried to ssh to mongodb container, it throws following error.

**Ssh into mongo docker**

```
docker exec -it mongodb /bin/bash
```

**Error**

```
connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: connect: connection refused": unknown
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: I am new to community. May I know why does it down voted?

Comment: You might want to ask this is this substack: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: why don't you post your docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

Please put result this command:

```
docker images | grep mongo
```

---

probably your container hasn't bash. you can test `/bin/sh` instead to `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Try docker exec -it mongo /bin/bash instead docker exec -it mongodb /bin/bash. Your container name it's mongo, not mongodb.

Comment: Nope, his container name is mongodb, mongo is the image name

Answer (score 0):

You can try run step 2 or try to remove this container **`docker rm 81b6c0c65e43`**  and run this 
 *1. **`docker run --name mongo --restart=always -d -p 27017:27017 mongo mongod --auth`***
 *2. **`docker exec -i -t mongo bash`***

[image: This my test (pic)]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of docker are you using ? You may have run into this [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36002) which seems to be resolved by the last docker-ce version (17.12.1-ce)